# /bin/bash is gone?

Tags: bash, git

I typed the following command, and now `bash` isn't working.

`$ sudo chmod a-x /bin/bash_old /bin/sh_old`

It just says:

`login: /bin/bash: No such file or directory.`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I suspect that you typed some other commands that actually caused this error. Did you do an `mv /bin/bash /bin/bash_old` or a `cp` followed by `rm /bin/bash`? Because it now looks like you don't have a `/bin/bash` on your system and that `/bin/bash` is set as your login shell in `/etc/passwd`. I would move the shells back to where they were to fix the problems.

I should point out that this is sort of a strange problem to run into. Perhaps you want to post a **new question** on this site that states what you're trying to do and asks for help at doing it.